# Add JavaDoc @author tag to every java file in my project

Tags: javadoc, author

I hava a Java project with a lot of files. In some of this I inserted a JavaDoc @author tag just before class/interface declaration, but not in all. I would like a script (bash, perl, whatever) able to add @author tag in the right position (just before class declaration) for all files that doesn't have one. Ho to find the right line where to add this javadoc?:

```
/*
 * @author alepac
 */
```

Comment: I recommend to completely do without this tag like discussed in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269843/javadoc-author-tag-good-practices/17271433#17271433

Answer (score 1):

Not a script but if your Java project happens to be built with [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/) then you could use the [javadoc:fix](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/fix-mojo.html) goal of [Javadoc plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-javadoc-plugin/) which you can configure so that it inserts the `@author` tag wherever it's missing including the cases where there is no javadoc at all:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
    <configuration>
        <fixTags>author</fixTags>
        <force>true</force>
        <fixFieldComment>false</fixFieldComment>
        <fixMethodComment>false</fixMethodComment>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the following script,

```
#!/bin/bash

function proccess_all_files {
FILES="./*"
cd "$1"
for i in $FILES
do
if [[ -d "$i" ]]; then
echo "Directory $i found...no action taken"
else
echo "Processing $i file..."
sed '/*
 * @author alepac
 */' $i > $i.bak
mv "$i.bak" "$i"
fi
done
for j in * .[!.]* ..?*; do
cd "$1"
test -d "$1/$j" && proccess_all_files "$1/$j"
done
}

proccess_all_files "`DIRECTORY NAME`"
```

Let me know whether it helped you or not, or whether this is exactly what you are looking for or not.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm not a sed guru but it's usually used for pattern substitution not concatenation (I usually use cat) and I didn't understand your syntax. Moreover, as explained above, I don't want to insert the javadoc in topo of the file but just before class/interface declaration as specified by javadocs.

Comment: Without using `sed`, I guess you need to use some of the editor which will write the .bak file for you. I just had this script for the same problem of mine. But still, It was worth sharing, atleast will give you some idea about how it is getting done.. Sorry if it wasn't that helpful...