# Is the author tag required in JavaDoc or not?

Tags: java, javadoc

Regardless of common convention / best-practice (as I know many people deride `@author` as bad-practice), but instead relying on official sources, is the `@author` tag required in JavaDoc or not?

Investigating this question, I looked into Oracle's own documentation at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/index-137868.html (this is also the first result in Google when searching for 'javadoc tags').

In a section called "order of tags", they say:

> Include tags in the following order:
>
> - `@author` (classes and interfaces only, required)
> - `@version` (classes and interfaces only, required. See footnote 1)
> - `@param` (methods and constructors only)
> - `@return` (methods only)
> - `@exception` (`@throws` is a synonym added in Javadoc 1.2)
> - `@see`
> - `@since`
> - `@serial` (or `@serialField` or `@serialData`)
> - `@deprecated` (see How and When To Deprecate APIs)

Here it seems that `@author` is marked as "required", even when something like `@return` is not. This seemed quite strange to me. Indeed, later on in the exact same document I found the following statement:

> You can provide one @author tag, multiple @author tags, or no @author
>   tags.

This seems to me to be a complete contradiction. If you can provide no `@author` tags, surely it's not "required"!

Have I misread something or is this just poorly-written documentation?

Comment: “many people deride @author as bad-practice…” I have never heard anyone say that.  While I don’t know anyone who thinks of `@author` as required, everyone I know who places any value on javadoc to begin with seems to appreciate the value of being able to consult the original authors before making a fundamental modification to a class.

Comment: @VGR for example, here it is described as "unwanted noise": http://stackoverflow.com/a/17271433/191761

Comment: @Kidburla So one answer on SO countervails all common sense about accountability, audit trails, who did what and when, ... ? Please.

Comment: That answer is, well, wrong.  An @author tag is much more useful than version control.  And it’s not meant to be a replacement for version control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say poorly written documentation.

The next paragraph says:

> The @author tag is not critical, because it is not included when
>   generating the API specification, and so it is seen only by those
>   viewing the source code. (Version history can also be used for
>   determining contributors for internal purposes.)

Additionally, no where is these tech notes can I see a statement stating it is required http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#javasourcefiles

Answer (score 3):

The document you are citing is a style guide, not the Javadoc specification:

> This document describes the style guide, tag and image conventions we use in documentation comments for Java programs written at Java Software, Oracle.

It is not an 'official source' for anything, unless you work at Oracle.